# Is there a way to get WP7 Mail to work with GMail conversations?

Tags: windows-phone-7, smtp

I've looked at the SMTP headers for outgoing mail, and Windows Phone doesn't seem to be setting the `In-Reply-To` or `References` fields, which I believe GMail uses to set up conversations.

Is there a way to enable these, or some other way to get gmail to detect replies as part of a conversation?

Answer (score 0):

I used the default settings to set up my GMail account and sync it to my Windows Phone. Conversations are working by default.

I take it that by conversations, you mean threaded view?

Comment: Yes. When an email is sent from the phone, it doesn't set those SMTP fields so GMail starts a new thread.